# android apk location

Tags: android, apk

I'm trying to copy some apk's of installed apps from my Milestone with FroyoMod installed.
While some apk's are in /system/data after installation, others are not there and I couldn't find any other directory where they are.
How to find out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess I solved it:
The Astro file manager I used to look for the apk's shows me empty /data/app directory.
However after connecting through adb, I see the apk's there and can also copy them with the shell.

Answer (score 1):

Sure the above is true but sounds difficult. FX Files manager with the root addin installed correctly, will allow you to brows and delele/rename.